# difference between two URL strings

Tags: php, string

I build

```
define('SITE_URL', siteURL()); //returns http://example.com/dir/
define('CKEDITOR', SITE_URL.'plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js');
```

What is the string operation to find the *'difference'* between the `SITE_URL` and the `full URL` aka `http://example.com/dir/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js` so that I only return the `plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str_replace($site_url, '', $fullurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer

```
function siteURL()
{
    return "http://example.com/dir/";
}

define('SITE_URL', siteURL()); //returns http://example.com/dir/
define('CKEDITOR', SITE_URL.'plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js');

// ignore the previous code is just to emulate your constants and functions
// the answer is the following line:

echo str_replace(SITE_URL,'',CKEDITOR);
```

working example here: http://3v4l.org/svTYm